# No [place] left to hide

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

This is about [place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/place) (189 questions as of writing this)

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No. There is no tag description. Looking at the questions

- a number of them seem to be about [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) which has its own tag [google-places-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-places-api)
- some of them pertain to a physical location in google maps which again has its own tag [google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps).
- physical location in any other API/programming language
- position in a website/page/template [exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368875/css-rail-in-the-left-and-right-end-of-a-website),[exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832667/shortcode-output-appearing-on-top-of-post-content-in-wordpress-what-am-i-doing)
- The `place` geometry manager in python's tkinter library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40515666/how-to-use-place-inside-a-frame-embedded-in-a-canvas)

etc... (may have missed some other meanings derived by askers)

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Not if it means physical location. It is a meta tag if it means website/template position. API specific can have (or already has) its own tag.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

No

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No

Can we burn it down?

Comment: Wait, is there really a Python API named "Place"? In that case, a [place] tag would have its uses, wouldn't it. As long as we make sure the tag isn't used for other things.

Comment: And to those who would suggest renaming the [place] tag to [python-place]: no. Just, no.

Comment: @MrLister from the question it looked more like a function in tkinter.. https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/place.htm

Comment: @MrLister the tag [place] by itself is ambiguous. IMO there needs to be a specifically named [place-api] or some such with an appropriate wiki if its needed(I havent used python to give the  suggestion for the name)

Comment: `place` in the `tkinter` module for Python is one of three geometry managers. The other two (pack and grid) don't have their own tags, I don't see a reason why `place` should?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring, Q +107/-0

Comment: @EthanField They don't have their own tag just because they aren't as popular right?
Burn/disable `place`, and make a new tag `tkinter-place`

Comment: @Worthy7 Debatable, in my experience I see more use of the other two geometry managers but all three are powerful and useful in their own right. I suppose it really just depends on the application you're building. And I don't really think we'd need a whole tag for any of the geometry managers specifically, I don't think they'd be used enough, but that's just a hunch and not backed up by anything.

Comment: @EthanField Yea that's fair enough. The problem here is just simply that `place` is too ambiguous. So IMO it should be disabled and from there nature will fix the rest. (people will use other more relevant tags / create a new better tag) I was just thinking we could help speed the natural course up a bit by creating one tag at least. If it's correct people will us it, if not people won't - no biggie, just like all the other underused tags

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring, Q +197/-0. It has been decided to burninate the tag

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/place) has been *burninated*.

[image]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

#### Observations/Retag Guidance:

Questions in this tag are fragmented across different topics. It's a very ambiguous tag, which deserves burnination. A few observations are:

- Questions about the Google Places API should be retagged to [google-places-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-places-api).
- Questions about physical location in Google Maps should be retagged to [google-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps).
- Questions related to a physical place should be retagged with the technology related to physical location. Some examples of such technologies are [gps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gps), [leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/leaflet), [openlayers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openlayers), and [postgis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgis). [location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/location) should *not* be used, since it is also ambiguous.

In most cases, the [place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/place) tag can simply be dropped without making much of a difference. It can be dropped from:

- Questions related to the Tkinter place function. As mentioned in the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363504/should-we-burninate-the-place-tag#comment558855_363504), "`place` in the `tkinter` module for Python is one of three geometry managers". There is no need to create a separate tag for it.
- Questions where it doesn't make much sense to have the tag. For example, about places on a website, or places inside a path, etc. There is a high chance that these posts are off-topic.
- Questions related to decimal place. Usually other tags would be helpful here.

---

## Progress:

The [place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/place) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=place),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplace%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplace%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplace%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bplace%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/place) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/place) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/place) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: I prefer not tagging questions with any of these tags if they simply mention any of these keywords. Questions has to be about the concept expressed in the tag. If a question about a GIS api mentions that the same doesn't happen with the google-maps api, then using google maps tag is not correct.

Comment: I wonder is `location` tag any better... Can you be expert in location, is that one on-topic for this site? [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613934/turtles-location-in-netlogo) turtles location in netlogo... [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49589227/change-location-after-video-is-finished) javascript "location".. just few of the first results using the tag

Comment: @eis My thoughts exactly. [tag:location] is equally ambiguous and should not be used, either. The only kind of "expertise" in "location" I can think of is GIS. If it's somehow related to actual physical locations, it should be tagged with [tag:gps] or whatever GIS technologies are involved.

Comment: Guys, remember that this answer is a community wiki answer. I have just added my thoughts as an user. Do update it if you feel that [location] is as bad as [place]

Comment: @BhargavRao ...How do we avoid an edit war without coming to a consensus on what to actually do first? And how to we come to any sort of agreement without discussing first?

Comment: If there's an edit war @jpmc26, then I'll jump in as a moderator. :-) ... As you can see that eis's comment has enough support you can go ahead and update it. Then (hypothetically), there'll be another comment which mentions that eis's comment is wrong and [location] is a better tag, if enough people agree on that and not on eis's then we'll update the answer again to roll back those changes. (That's how it's been done usually).

Comment: @BhargavRao I edited, but I'd appreciate it if you could review and edit if you think anything needs improvement. A more diverse set of example tags wouldn't hurt, either.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'll pass it on to the burnination team, they're more well versed than me in these matters.

Comment: @eis please note that "no-one is an expert at this tag" is a bad reason for burnination, as stated by [Shog9 himself](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/41347848#41347848). Burnination requests should instead be based on the [four criteria given by Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/325771).

Comment: @jpmc26 see my comment above here ^

Comment: @Adriaan You don't need to focus on that, the tag has other problems mentioned. Note the "is that one on-topic for this site" part of my comment, and my examples showing the umambiguity problem in the tag (which was already hinted to in the original burnination request, where it mentions physical location).

Comment: @BhargavRao There are no open questions left in the tag. Can complete this now